# How to delete a bunch of files in a folder knowing a part of their filename?

Tags: files, delete, filename, batch

I have a folder of Markdown files. The files use the following filename convention: `[Time-based ID] [Title]`. With this convention, you have filenames such as `202204101548 Banana bread` or `202204101549 Banana cake`.

Problem is, I want to delete a bunch of these files.

It would be too time consuming to delete them one by one, so that's out of the question. And that's all I can think of. I'm not knowledgeable enough about Linux to come up with a solution of my own. And attempting to gain the necessary knowledge is a bit out of my league right now. So, I'm asking you for your help.

I know that my request may sound a little lazy by my part, but I think that at the very least, some of you will have a nice problem to chew on.

The time-based ID of the files:

```
202106130712
202106200737
202106200757
202106200743
202106200845
202106130905
202106200728
202106200732
202106200752
202106200813
202106130847
202106200804
202106200815
202106200808
202106191046
202106191110
202106201003
202106191117
202106200724
202106090937
202106090918
202106101133
202106101134
202106110731
202106101135
202106110708
202106110713
202106110718
202106110751
202106110732
202106110756
202106110714
202106130714
202106201030
202106201032
202106130948
202106120959
202106101026
202106141032
202106130942
202106121006
202106121027
202106130914
202106130936
202106130940
202106130841
202106190907
202106101028
202106120908
202106130943
202106130839
202106101027
202106101024
202106190911
202106140742
202106140802
202106140735
202106101132
202106190947
202106190958
202106121022
202106130832
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide me. I'll provide information or act on request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all filenames start with `2021`, try for a dry-run (from within the directory containing the files):

```
find -type f -name "2021*"
```

and if satisfied with the output, (from within the directory containing the files) delete with:

```
find -type f -name "2021*" -delete
```

---

To exactly delete using a list of "time-based IDs" from a file, try this for a dry-run *(change `file` to the name of the file containing the list of IDs each on a new line exactly like the example in your question)*:

```
while IFS= read l; do
   find -type f -name "$l*"
done < file
```

If satisfied with the output, delete with:

```
while IFS= read l; do
   find -type f -name "$l*" -delete
done < file
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. That wouldn't do it. There are files created on 2021 that are not the ones I want to delete.

Comment: @Annabella I updated the answer to address this issue

Comment: Yo, this is nuts! Your solution using the list did it. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use wildcards.

```
mv *[0-9]*
```

deletes files that have a digit.

```
mv *[12]*
```

will delete all files with a 1 or a 2.

```
mv 2021[01][3-6]*
```

will delete 202103* through 202106* and 202113* through 202116*

If you want to do a dry-run you can replace "rm" by "ls" and it will echo on screen what would be deleted. So ...

```
ls *[1-3][a-c]*
```

will list all files containing the combinations 1a, 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, 2c, 3a, 3b, 3c.

Comment: First of all, thanks for commenting. Now for the comment itself. If I understand you correctly, you're proposing to delete all files that were created within a period. For example, all files created from 2022-04-11 to 2022-04-19. If so, then that would bring another problem: There might be files in between that I don't want to delete. How would you work around that?

Comment: either create wildcards to match all you want to delete or create more then 1 rm with wildecards. You can use the ! to reverse it so *[!0]* will not delete files with a 0. if you need you could also make a text file out of all the names, insert that file into libeoffice and use that to remove the filenames and then remove the files that are still inside this txt file. The thing is: the more difficult your remove is the more manual it will become. BTW it is also possible to remove on CONTENT of a file if that would help

Comment: In regards to the wildcards, I think that's a little too complex of a solution. I do like the idea of libreoffice, but I didn't and won't try it because I used Raffa's solution. Still, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the rm command.
Say I have 20 files named text01.txt, text02.txt, text03.txt etc.
I can use:

```
rm -f text*
```

The -f options means force (doesn't ask if you want to delete the file)
and all the aforementioned files will get deleted.
in your case try

```
rm -f *banana...(w/e)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment and welcome. I don't think that this will do. The folder contains many other files. Some are created on the same year or within the period of the files to remove. Some that I don't want to delete use words used in the filename of the files to delete.